# Oracle Unifier image data to be displayed in BI Report, image data is showing just a number

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Oracle Unifier image data to be displayed in BI Publisher Report, image data in the field is showing just a number. like 446 and there is another field which show a jpg file name only like 2121.jpg. And when I looked at many post around found that there is some data inside.
like below. You might have noticed on right side the example is blob i.e. some string data is there. In the unfier i just got a field value 446. So my question is how do I go about displaying the image. 
I refered to this document but could not get anywhere
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E91461_01/English/Install_and_Upgrade/Configuring/bi_publish/unifier_bi_publisher_config.pdf
and I also tried [Another way to work on getting the image](https://it.toolbox.com/question/display-blob-images-dynamically-in-xml-publisher-report-122909)
but again i have the same problem my field is in numnber the people trying it out have field value in blob
 https://community.oracle.com/thread/4095157
[image]
[enter link description here](https://community.oracle.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-14585212-451840/pastedImage_4.png)

Below is what I worked on and got to this point. 
Image in BI Publisher report from the data is not displaying. I have followed the instructions and created the url and saved it in the ALT text of the image in RTF it is not displaying the image. Below are the instructions that I have followed. 
Page 16 --> Configuring BI Publisher Reports to Use Unifier Images from the below document
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E91461_01/English/Install_and_Upgrade/Configuring/bi_publish/unifier_bi_publisher_config.pdf

The ALT Text in the image is --> url:{concat($uuu_p_urlF,'/',COMLOGO,'/',//security_token/SEC_TOKEN[1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E91461_01/English/Install_and_Upgrade/Configuring/bi_publish/unifier_bi_publisher_config.pdf))}
It id generating the correct url -->http://IPADD/bluedoor/rest/image/453/A30DEAC4-4C63-12C7-3071-7A19048E848F
If i use this url i can see the image in the browser but the same link in the ALT Text field of the image does not display the image.

Would like to to what I am doign wrong

Comment: The image you are linking is from the oracle community thread. Can you share your template and datafile?

Comment: please see what I have added to the question on what I have worked on the problem